# How do I split a string by a multiple-string delimiter in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class SplitTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String[] strToSplit = new String[] { "GH", "MN" };
        for (String de : strToSplit) {
            if (string.contains(de)) {
                String[]str = string.split(de);
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(str[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
ABCDEF,IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,ABCDEFGHIJKL,OPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

but actual output is :

```
ABCDEF,IJKL,OPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: [Running your program produces the output you expect](http://ideone.com/bmMxVv). Voting to close as non-reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it another way like replace string by unique delimiter at first place instead of splitting string at first place .Later you can split whole string by unique delimiter. for ex.

```
 public class SplitTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String str;
    String[] strToSplit = new String[] { "GH", "MN" };
    for (String de : strToSplit) {
        if (string.contains(de)) {
             str = string.replace(de,unique_delimiter);

        }
    }
  String [] finalString = str.split(unique_delimiter);
   for (int i = 0; i < finalString.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(finalString[i]);
            }
}
}
```

Hope this would help.